# NavigationController is null

Tags: ios, xamarin, mvvmcross

Can someone explain me why I get the NavigationController null everywhere I want to access it, even though the Presenter class from MvvmCross seems to initialise one?

Bellow is my current code, I tried multiple ways to get the NavigationController, but none of them worked.

The purpose of this is to hide it on the first screen of the app (Login).
How to achieve this?

AppDelegate.cs

```
    [Register("AppDelegate")]
public class AppDelegate : MvxApplicationDelegate
{
    private UIWindow window;

    public override bool FinishedLaunching(UIApplication application, NSDictionary launchOptions)
    {
        window = new UIWindow(UIScreen.MainScreen.Bounds);
        var presenter = new MvxIosViewPresenter(this, window);

        var setup = new Setup(this, presenter);
        setup.Initialize();

        var startup = Mvx.Resolve<IMvxAppStart>();
        startup.Start();

        window.MakeKeyAndVisible();

        return true;
    }
}
```

LoginScreen.cs

```
public partial class LoginScreen : MvxViewController
{
    private UITabBarController tabBarController;

    public new LoginViewModel ViewModel
    {
        get { return (LoginViewModel)base.ViewModel; }
        set { base.ViewModel = value; }
    }

    public LoginScreen()
    {
        NavigationController.SetToolbarHidden(true, false);

        tabBarController = new UITabBarController();
        tabBarController.View.Frame = new CGRect(0, 0, View.Bounds.Width, 450);

        var tab1 = new UIViewController();
        tab1.Title = "tab1";
        tab1.View.BackgroundColor = UIColor.Green;
        var tab2 = new UIViewController();
        tab2.Title = "tab2";
        tab2.View.BackgroundColor = UIColor.Orange;
        var tab3 = new UIViewController();
        tab3.Title = "tab3";
        tab3.View.BackgroundColor = UIColor.Red;

        tabBarController.ViewControllers = new UIViewController[] { tab1, tab2, tab3 };

        var cgrect = new CGRect(0, 510, View.Bounds.Width, 45);
        var button = new UIButton(UIButtonType.Custom)
        {
            BackgroundColor = UIColor.Green,
        };
        button.SetTitle("click", UIControlState.Normal);
        button.Frame = cgrect;

        View.AddSubviews(new UIView[] { tabBarController.View, button });

        var swipeLeft = new UISwipeGestureRecognizer(HandleLeftSwipe)
        {
            Direction = UISwipeGestureRecognizerDirection.Left
        };
        var swipeRight = new UISwipeGestureRecognizer(HandleRightSwipe)
        {
            Direction = UISwipeGestureRecognizerDirection.Right
        };
        tabBarController.View.AddGestureRecognizer(swipeLeft);
        tabBarController.View.AddGestureRecognizer(swipeRight);
    }
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The reason as to why the `NavigationController` property is null in your constructor, is because it is not attached to the `UINavigationViewController` at that point of the lifecycle.

You should preferably set up UI inside of an override of `ViewDidLoad`

Comment: Awesome! I had a strong feeling that I already tried that but it seems after moved everything from the constructor, the NavigationController wasn't null anymore. Only problem now is that it doesn't hide, do you have any idea why this would happen?

Comment: I think you need to use the SetNavigationBarHidden method instead of SetToolbarHidden.

Comment: Yup! Have to pay more attention next time, got lost in first problem and now didn't thought to much on this. Thank you for your help and big thumbs up for the contribution within the Xamarin community, found a lot of helpful info from you!

Comment: To the people downvoting the answer, please add a reason in the comments.